# Does each call to printf() create a new internal buffer, or do all subsequent calls use the same buffer as the first?

Tags: c, printf, c-strings

When I was working on a small program using `printf()`, I noticed that each `\t` character used in following `printf()` calls continued from the end of the string in the previous `printf()` call.

The following image and code example will clarify what I mean.

Example of expected output

[image: screenshot of tabular output]

```
printf("\t%d", i); // Prints multiples of 1
printf("\t%d", i * 2); // Prints multiple of 2
printf("\t%d", i * 3); // ... multiple of 3
printf("\t%d", i * 4); // ... multiple of 4
printf("\t%d", i * 5); // ... multiple of 5
printf("\n"); // Starts new line after each number printed.
```

To get the desired output in the image above, I was expecting to have to do this:

```
printf("\t%d", i);
printf("\t\t%d", i * 2);
printf("\t\t\t%d", i * 3);
printf("\t\t\t\t%d", i * 4);
printf("\t\t\t\t\t%d", i * 5);
```

But this didn't work, each following printf() call continued from the end of the previous string, which makes sense because we aren't working with new lines.

Ultimately, I decided that a single printf call does the same thing, though slightly less readable, and probably has less overhead.

```
printf("\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\n", i, i, i * 2, i * 3, i * 4, i * 5);
```

This made me curious about how printf() works. Does each subsequent call to the function use the same internal buffer created by the first call?

Thank you!

Comment: What difference does it make?

Comment: It's not the `printf` calls that handles buffering, it's the `FILE` streams that does. The `printf` function writes to `stdout` which have its own buffer. How, when and where the `stdout` (or any `FILE` stream) buffer is actually created is largely irrelevant.

Comment: And for the simple case you show, the "overhead" is negligible. The writing of the text to the console is probably far slower than the six `printf` calls.

Comment: Lastly, thinking about such things beforehand is usually *premature optimization* which often leads to bad code. Concentrate on writing good, readable and maintainable code first and foremost. Then if there are some efficiency requirements (and the programs is not "good enough" (which often *is* good enough)) then measure and profile and benchmark to find the bottlenecks and hot-spots, and concentrate on the worst of those first. With proper documentation and commenting (since optimizations usually make code near unmaintainable).

Comment: Using a new/the same buffer wouldn't explain what you are seeing.

Comment: The answer is: It depends on your implementation. Nothing else can be asserted.

Comment: Interestingly, `#include <stdio.h> int main(void) { printf("%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n", "Number", "1st", "2nd", "3rd", "4th", "5th"); for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) { printf("%d", i); printf("\r\t%d", i); printf("\r\t\t%d", i * 2); printf("\r\t\t\t%d", i * 3); printf("\r\t\t\t\t%d", i * 4); printf("\r\t\t\t\t\t%d", i * 5); putchar('\n'); } return 0; } ` — with `\r` at the start of each `printf()` after the first within the loop — does produce your desired output, at least on a Mac.  The tab is a non-destructive overwriting character, unlike a blank would be.  YMMV, though.

Comment: I _assumed_ that `printf()` used its own buffer and that each call would allocate new memory, so that's what was confusing about the `\t` behavior, but the answers and comments clarified things. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that this

> ```
> printf("\t%d", i);
> printf("\t\t%d", i * 2);
>     // other printf elided for brevity
> ```

is not equivalent to what you are seeking.  Specifically, it appears you believe *incorrectly* that each call of `printf()` returns the cursor to the start of a line (e.g. on the terminal).

In reality, the second call of `printf()` writes immediately after the integral value printed by the first, on the same line.

The output is sequential so

```
printf("\t%d", i);
printf("\t\t%d", i * 2);     // total of three \t in this and preceding statement
```

is equivalent (in terms of complete data output) to

```
printf("\t%d\t\t%d", i, i*2);    // note the 3 \t here.
```

not to

```
printf("\t%d\t%d", i, i*2);      //  only two \t here
```

This behaviour has nothing to do with buffering.

Answer (score 2):

First of all `printf()` does not handle buffer memory directly.Suppose it uses the `fwrite()` function call(which also uses a system call `write()`) for writing anything to any file and this function handles buffer memory.It contains a `pointer` to next where last character was written. `fwrite()` function writes the data in a specific file.`printf()` requests the `fwrite()` to write data in a specific file called `stdout`.

Every time when you call `printf()` function it calls `fwrite()` function to write data on `stdout`.
Suppose you want to print `"Hello World"`, you can print it with on single call of `printf`

```
printf("Hello World\n");
```

OR

```
printf("Hello ");
printf("World");
printf("\n");
```

So you can call it with 3 `printf`, this will call `fwrite()` 3 times and this function will remember the position where data is to be written next.For eg:- In last call `printf("\n")` the position will set to next line.

Comment: Are you sure about your claim that `printf()` uses `fwrite()`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler No, I am just giving the idea how it can be interpreted.

Comment: That's not what your answer says.  Your answer says "[`printf()`] uses the `fwrite()` call" with no caveats about "you can consider that it behaves as if …" or anything similar.

Comment: `printf` does not necessarily call `fwrite` (in fact on implementations I'm familiar with, it doesn't call that at all; it uses `fputc`).

Comment: 'Tis interesting. The POSIX specification generally marks differences between itself and the C standard, but [`fprintf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fprintf.html) says _"Characters generated by `fprintf()` and `printf()` are printed as if `fputc()` had been called."_  It doesn't add any markers for that, but it is not present in the C11 standard ([C11 §7.21.6.1 The `fprintf` function](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1)).  Note the all-important "as if".  C99 doesn't mention that either, AFAICT, and neither did C90.

Answer (score 0):

Printf prints exactly as if you're typing something by hand. Unless you explicitly tell it to do so, it doesn't go back to the beginning of the line. So when printf gets asked to print "\ta" and "\tb" it first outputs

```
    a|
     ^- And leaves the "cursor" here...
```

so when you ask it to print "\tb", it resumes from where it left off, and prints:

```
    a    b
```